# AngularJS limitTo filter not evaluating expressions

Tags: angularjs

I want to show half the elements in an array initially as follows;

```
<div ng-show="showHalf" ng-repeat="item in itemList | limitTo: itemList.length/2">{{item}}</div>
<div ng-show="!showHalf" ng-repeat="item in itemList>{{item}}</div>
<a ng-click="showHalf = !showHalf">{{showHalf? 'Show less' : 'Show all'}}</a>
```

However, the `limitTo` filter seems to be unable to evaluate `itemList.length/2`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you set it in the controller? `$scope.limit = $scope.itemList.length/2;`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey setting the limit in a controller works, why can't I do it in the view?

Comment: It **is** working and has the right syntax. But none of your provided code can replicate the error.

Comment: Yea, this is also working in the view. Please add more code or create a plnkr / fiddle. -> http://jsfiddle.net/hesj1nwo/

Answer (score 0):

The code written by you is correct.

Check for the following:

1. **showHalf** value: May be showHalf value is false which is why second HTML line is getting rendered
2. **anchor tag**: Try clicking it and see if the array list display reduces to half